# How do I prevent my html elements from changing position when resizing my webpage?

Tags: html, css, header

I have a header for my website that looks good fullscreen on a 1080p resolution, but if I shrink the website or move it to a larger resolution like 1440p, the elements move out of position or overlap. Example below of how it should look [image: how it should look]

This is how it looks when I change resolutions: [image]

Or if I cut the screen in half: [image]

Is there a way to fix this? My header :

```
header {
background-color: #032541;
position: relative;
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
height: 70px;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
max-width: 100%;}
```

I used this format for my html, my code just has different contents than the example below, but it is a ul with many li a elements inside. I got the example from https://codetheweb.blog/style-a-navigation-bar-css/

```
<header>
       <img src="https://codetheweb.blog/assets/img/icon2.png">
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Terms of use</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
```

I was using padding-left to move each item to the position I wanted it, is there a better way? Im not sure how to create a header/nav bar where the elements are split up with space between. Thank you.

Comment: did you check out css-grid. I think css-grid is a great tool for responsive website.

Comment: Can you reproduce it in jsfiddle or codepen?